# Regex possible with sometimes deviating rules in log?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to create a tool with which I can analyse a log.

However, the log file is a trace of an application where sometimes abnormal things happen such as:

- An event spread over several lines.
- The text sometimes also contains characters that I want to filter on in a split function.

Now I am trying to use a regex to get all the values out of this trace log, is this really possible because of the deviations in the log?

**The log includes a few deviations that may occur:**

```
[111111111111111] [22222222] [33][4][5555] [6666.............text..........6666] [7777777]
19.03.21 18:45:48 EF22       37D8 2 TIMEST 02 TIGetTicketImprintingLayoutStart:  :13254125
19.03.21 18:45:48 EF22       37D8 2 TIMEST 02 TIGetTicketImprintingLayoutEnd:  :13254140
19.03.21 18:46:11 EF21       36C8 1 TIMEST 00 PdlActivated: OnAWS :13276343
19.03.21 18:51:30 ColService 3D20 0 ABLAUF Uploading 1 trace files from device number 50... :13595671
19.03.21 15:08:41 AUTSTART01 2678 0 MEMORY Actual memory usage:
 Process              ( PID) Workingset Pagefile Starttime           Priority Commandline
 WmiPrvSE             (080C)   9028 KB   2344 KB                               
 WmiPrvSE             (0E98)  16612 KB   7248 KB                               
 WtsCP                (2388)  42800 KB  24396 KB 2021.03.19 15:06:58 Normal   "C:\Program Files (x86)\XXXXXXXXXX\Misc\WTSCP.EXE" 
 WtsCP                (2988)  48052 KB  26444 KB 2021.03.19 15:07:19 Normal   WtsCp.exe 
 ZapService           (0AD0)  19400 KB  25708 KB                               
 :227156
19.03.21 15:08:41 AUTSTART01 2678 0 INFO:  PlistThread finished :227156
19.03.21 15:08:41 QW01       27C0 0 DB:    Database encryption for CENTRAL is enabled. :227203
19.03.21 15:08:42 QW01       27C0 0 DB:    Download: MVKARTEDATEN (BULK Size: 1000) :227296
19.03.21 15:08:43 AF188      3664 0 SR:    Barrier Motor Info:  state is down 0° / livetime 646-16:31:54  67176 cycles / 32°C Input 233951mV 50251mHz / DC Link Voltage 394 internalSupply 14115mV PhaseU 0mA PhaseW 0mA Restarts 0 :228796
19.03.21 15:08:44 EF178      3750 0 SR:    Barrier Motor Info:  state is down 0° / livetime 647-15:40:59  7927 cycles / 27°C Input 231829mV 50251mHz / DC Link Voltage 320 internalSupply 14039mV PhaseU 0mA PhaseW 0mA Restarts 0 :229593
19.03.21 15:08:44 EF26       362C 0 INFO:  RestartInfo: RestartReason = 04, EMReason FE, RunningSince = 2-03:20:09, RequestedCount = 1 :229953
19.03.21 15:08:44 QW01       27C0 0 DB:     7735 Records copied ! :230078
19.03.21 15:08:44 QW01       27C0 0 DB:    Download: MVKARTEDATENSERIENNR (BULK Size: 1000) :230078
19.03.21 15:08:45 AF45       35B4 0 INFO:  RestartInfo: RestartReason = 04, EMReason FE, RunningSince = 2-03:20:14, RequestedCount = 1 :230656
19.03.21 15:09:17 MENU09      CCC 0 !!!:   Warning: w_mailbox.wf_openchannelex4 get possibly wrong hostname (0506113-09) from GetHostComputerName. Replace with current computername: 0506113-01 :262265
19.03.21 15:09:17 MENU09      CCC 0 MAIN:  OperatingSystemVersion: Windows Server 2012 (602) :262328
19.03.21 15:09:17 MENU09      CCC 0 MAIN:  Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU12) (KB4536648) - 13.0.5698.0 (X64) 
    Feb 15 2020 01:47:30 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) :262328
19.03.21 15:09:17 MENU09      CCC 0 MAIN:  SQL @@LANGUAGE: us_english :262343
```

**What values I want to be able to get out of it eventually**

```
[1] datetimeValue = 19.03.21 18:45:48
[2] processShortName = EF22, AUTSTART01, QW01, etc. (max 10 characters)
[3] threadID = 37D8 (Heximal)
[4] traceLevel = 1-8 (1 digit)
[5] tracedProcess = TIMEST, INFO, DB, MAIN (max 6 characters)
[6] text = <everything between [tracedProcess] and : (at the end of the line)> (this can sometime be spread over multiple lines)
[7] msTimestamp = the value after the last : (ms since start of trace process)
```

Now I do it with `Substring()`and `Split()` but of course I do not get everything filtered the way I want, only the happy flow when everything is on one line, not when it is spread over several lines.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been parsing files for over 40 years.  This is code I would use

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LogFile logFile = new LogFile(FILENAME);
        }
    }

    public class LogFile
    {
        const string DATE_FORMAT = "dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss";
        const string pattern = @"^(?'date'.{17})\s+(?'shortName'[^\s]+)\s+(?'threadID'[^\s]+)\s+(?'traceLevel'\d+)\s+(?'processID'[^\s]+)";
        DateTime startTime { get; set; }
        List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
        List<string> shortNames { get; set; }
        List<string> traceProcess { get; set; }
        DateTime endTime { get; set; }

        public LogFile(string filename)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            string line = "";
            Thread thread = null;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!line.StartsWith("["))
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith(" "))
                    {
                        if (thread.text == null) thread.text = new List<string>();
                        thread.text.Add(line);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        thread = new Thread();
                        threads.Add(thread);
                        Match match = Regex.Match(line, pattern);
                        string dateStr = match.Groups["date"].Value;
                        thread.date  = DateTime.ParseExact(line.Substring(0, 17), DATE_FORMAT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        thread.shortName = match.Groups["shortName"].Value;
                        if (thread.shortName.Length > 10) thread.shortName.Substring(0, 10);
                        thread.threadId = match.Groups["threadID"].Value;
                        string traceLevelStr = match.Groups["traceLevel"].Value;
                        thread.traceLevel = int.Parse(traceLevelStr);
                        thread.processID = match.Groups["processID"].Value;
                        if (thread.processID.Length > 6) thread.processID.Substring(0, 6);
                    }
                }
                
            }
            startTime = threads.FirstOrDefault().date;
            endTime = threads.LastOrDefault().date;
            shortNames = threads.Select(x => x.shortName).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
            traceProcess = threads.Select(x => x.processID).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Thread
    {
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public string shortName { get; set; }
        public string threadId { get; set; }
        public string processID { get; set; }
        public int traceLevel { get; set; }
        public List<string> text { get; set; }

    }
}
```